# Use mttkinter in project

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I decided to use mttkinter in my project, but I have problem. I usually import tkinter like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
```

And I tried `mttkinter` like this import:

```
from mttkinter import *
root=Tk()
```

After this, I saw global name 'Tk' is not defined. 
What can I do with it?

Comment: If you normally import from `tkinter` (all lower case), then you appear to be using Python 3.x.  `mttkinter` is for 2.7 only, as far as I know.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org/mttkinter/ - please ensure you're on the right version

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a old question, but I had the same problem and found a solution.
As stated in the comments you're probably using Python 3.x. since you use "tkinter" all in lower case.

If you check the example from the [mtTkinter github](https://github.com/RedFantom/mtTkinter/blob/master/example.py).
You'll see that the example checks for the Python version installed and imports either "Tkinter" or "tkinter" before importing mtTkinter (I would assume, to make sure you have access to everything in tkinter even if mtTkinter is not up to date).

For your case (as for mine), your imports should be:

```
from tkinter import *
from mttkinter import mtTkinter

root = Tk()
```

Note that if we read what's in the code, your import should work, but you'd have to declare root as follows (I tested this import and it works):

```
from mttkinter import *

root = mtTkinter.Tk()
```

Again, I know this question is old, but the answer might be useful for someone else.
Cheers.